# How do I get data from website with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to get all address for all whale btc from website https://explorer.btc.com/btc/top-address
but the result is empty respones.xpath

My code is scrappy

```
response.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a").extract()
```

Comment: If you want people to help you please consider accepting their answers.

Answer (score 0):

The data is created [dynamically](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html). You can get it from the API.

Learn how to use [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) and devtools. Also check out the docs for json response.

Anyway what I did is: I opened the page in the browser and looked in the network tab under xhr, then I copied the url and the headers and recreated the request.

```py
scrapy shell

In [1]: headers = {
   ...: "Accept": "*/*",
   ...: "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   ...: "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   ...: "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   ...: "Connection": "keep-alive",
   ...: "DNT": "1",
   ...: "Host": "explorer.api.btc.com",
   ...: "Origin": "https://explorer.btc.com",
   ...: "Pragma": "no-cache",
   ...: "Referer": "https://explorer.btc.com/",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
   ...: "Sec-GPC": "1",
   ...: "TE": "trailers",
   ...: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.372
   ...: 9.169 Safari/537.36"
   ...: }

In [2]: url = 'https://explorer.api.btc.com/stats/address/rich/top?app_a=S2Q4QUljMHEwNzNoMAI5XdXXMAgwqxia4P8VScnvddXEG5
   ...: EguXvUEXk4ccTC&app_b=Kd8AIc0q073h0&nonce=DJI22151IXIC7512&timestamp=1639207870&coins=btc&max_count=100&page=1&p
   ...: age_size=50&sign=HHpvZxiIsZ0yUbRk0ZZ+1sdEyeC3MHnlAXBFLQPtNm0%3D'

In [3]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers)

In [4]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://explorer.api.btc.com/stats/address/rich/top?app_a=S2Q4QUljMHEwNzNoMAI5XdXXMAgwqxia4P8VScnvddXEG5EguXvUEXk4ccTC&app_b=Kd8AIc0q073h0&nonce=DJI22151IXIC7512&timestamp=1639207870&coins=btc&max_count=100&page=1&page_size=50&sign=HHpvZxiIsZ0yUbRk0ZZ+1sdEyeC3MHnlAXBFLQPtNm0%3D> (referer: https://explorer.btc.com/)

In [5]: json_data = response.json()

In [6]: for data in json_data['data']['btc']['list']:
   ...:     print(data['address'])
   ...:
34xp4vRoCGJym3xR7yCVPFHoCNxv4Twseo
bc1qgdjqv0av3q56jvd82tkdjpy7gdp9ut8tlqmgrpmv24sq90ecnvqqjwvw97
1P5ZEDWTKTFGxQjZphgWPQUpe554WKDfHQ
37XuVSEpWW4trkfmvWzegTHQt7BdktSKUs
38UmuUqPCrFmQo4khkomQwZ4VbY2nZMJ67
1FeexV6bAHb8ybZjqQMjJrcCrHGW9sb6uF
3LYJfcfHPXYJreMsASk2jkn69LWEYKzexb
...
...
...
...
...
```